# Changing CSS height property removes anchors?

Tags: css, navigation, height

I am working on a standard header/navigation for my website.

I started with having a CSS "height" value of 100% for the html, body elements but this resulted in the wrong layout.

However, when I change the CSS height property from "100%" to "auto", the layout is correct, but I lose the anchors. The text is still there (e.g "Advice", "Do It", "Home", Help") but the anchors (organized as list items) no longer appear in the navigation. I can't click on them anymore.

Why is this?

Here's my CSS:

```
html,body {
    height: auto;   /* This is the only property that I'm toggling */
    margin: 0; 
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 978px;
    font: 12px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    background: #000001 url('../images/bg-body.jpg') no-repeat 50% 0;  
}
#nav {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 2px 0 271px;
    list-style: none;
    background: url('../images/sep-nav.gif') no-repeat 100% 0;   
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 11px 0 0 2px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 128px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('../images/sep-nav.gif') no-repeat 0 -1px;
    display: inline;    
}
#nav li a {color: #FFFEFE;}
.....
```

Here's the header HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- header -->
        <div id="header">

                    <!-- logo -->
                    <h1 class="logo"><a href="home">Site Name</a></h1>

                    <!-- Feedback button -->
                    <div class="feed-w1">
                    <div class="feed-w2">
                <div class="feed">
                <span class="l"><a href="#">Feedback, please</a></span><span class="r"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Small links -->
                <div class="top-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sign out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <!-- Main Navigation -->
                <div class="frame">
                    <div class="holder">
                        <ul id="nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Advice</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Do it</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Your Profile</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- Search box -->
                        <div class="search-form">
                            <form action="#">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <legend class="hidden">Search Form</legend>
                                    <input class="text" type="text" value="Search" title="Search" />
                                    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                            </div>  
                </div>
    </body>
```

I compared the computed CSS in Firebug when the html, body height property was set to "auto" vs. "100%" and they were the same.

Can somebody please shed some light on how retain the anchors in the navigation while setting height to "auto"?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean you lose the anchors? You can't see them on screen at all? I created a test page with the html/css snippet above and I don't see any problems; maybe the issue is in another part of the page?

Comment: @Salil and @Dan M: I added my entire header/navigation HTML and clarified what I mean by "losing" anchors in the post above.

Comment: it works for in both the condition i am using linux-firfox .which browser you are using.

Answer (score 0):

JMan, I don't see any problems when running your code on a sample page

One suggestion - check your DOCTYPE declaration

I use strictly "strict" :) (pun intended)

either

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

(i tried your example with the first one)

Cheers,

hope you find a solution to your problem